# Cisco 3850 Switch Stack Issue

Tags: switch, switching

I had 4x3850 - Lan Base and 1x3850 - IP Base, i want to put then in to stack, i think its not possible but can we downgrade the 1x3850 - IP Base to LAN Base. If yes then How, please provide the steps.....
Waiting for your response.

Comment: Yeah, you're right you cannot stack mixed feature sets (http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3850-series-switches/product_bulletin_c25-720777.html - search for word `mix`). And I think you'll have to contact Cisco. Also see this: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3850-series-switches/deployment_guide_c07-727067.html#_Toc350855349

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable it with the right-to-use license:

```
Switch# license right-to-use deactivate ipbase all
Switch# reload
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stack them if they have different licenses. Yes, you can downgrade them with the help of Cisco License TAC at "Cisco Licensing Support" . Its painful but I have done it before.